# Not able to find SQL Server Agent in my SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to find SQL Server Agent in SQL Server. I tried this query which is shown in picture [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtqAS.png).

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Agent isn't available in SQL Server Express Edition, which is what you are running according to the image you attached. You'll have to upgrade to a paid version to have this feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have done the correct steps, but I'm guessing that you haven't started the SQL Server Agent service.

You can do this from SQL Server Configuration Manager by right-clicking the name of the service and select Start

[image]

Then if you refresh Management Studio, SQL Server Agent should be enabled.

Comment: Now I can't able to find Sql Server Configuration Manager in my system, Please help me.

Comment: @Ashok you can find the agent in the Server Services Window as well, where all other services are running

Comment: @Dean I am getting The SQL Server(SQL Express) service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.